# c serial programming as intermediaries

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, modbus, rs485

I am doing a project now to listen to the data between a PROFIBUS network that is between a master and slave. The setup would be that the master would be connected to Raspberry Pi and the Raspberry Pi would be connected to the slave.

So far, I am able to read the telegrams or messages sent by the master and send it to the slave. However, I can't get the respond of the slave. When the master is directly connected to the slave the communication is working.

This should be a very simple task because basically what I should program is just to read from master, write it to slave and get the slave's respond. I think maybe Im missing out on something, can you guys help me out? This is the code...

```
    .... include all library definitions..


    // GLOBAL VARIABLES
    char portMaster[] = "/dev/ttyAMA0";
    char portSlave[] = "/dev/ttyUSB0";


    // SERIAL PORT FUNCTIONS
    // Open the port to start reading and writing
    int openPort(char port[]) 
    {
        int fd; 
        .... do all the settings for serial port communication.....
        return fd;      
    } // end of openPort function


    // PROFIBUS TELEGRAM FUNCTIONS
    /*
    - get incoming telegrams from master and directly write them to the slave
    */
    int getPacketsFromMaster(int fdMaster, int fdSlave, int debug)
    {
        static unsigned char uartBuffer[MAX_BUFFER]; 
        int bytesRead = 0;
        // Loop indefinitely to get data
        while(1)
        {
                bytesRead = read(fdMaster, &uartBuffer[0], 20); // read the ports
                // read until the telegram is complete, code not shown here
                break;
         }
         write(fdSlave, &uartBuffer[0], length);
         return 1;
    }


    // Get Packets from Slave and directly write to the master
    int getPacketsFromSlave(int fdSlave, int fdMaster, int debug)
    {
        static unsigned char uartBuffer[MAX_BUFFER]; 
        int bytesRead = 0;
        // Loop indefinitely to get data
        while(1)
        {
                bytesRead = read(fdSlave, &uartBuffer[0], 20); // read the ports
                // read until the telegram is complete, code not shown here   
                break;        
         }
         write(fdMaster, &uartBuffer[0], length);//length came from header
         return 1;
    }       


    int main(void)
    {
            // open ports
            int fdMaster = openPort(portMaster);
            int fdSlave = openPort(portSlave);
            if(fdSlave == -1 || fdMaster == -1)
            {
                printf("Operation halted!!!! Exiting Now");
                return 0;
            }

            int status;
        while(1)
        {
            status = getPacketsFromMaster(fdMaster, fdSlave, 1);
            if(status)
                getPacketsFromSlave(fdSlave, fdMaster, 1);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

The code is shortened, since most of the codes are really basic like setting up the serial port. As said earlier, the function *getPacketsFromMaster* is able to read perfectly from the master. The function *getPacketsFromSlave* has a timeout, because the slave does not need to respond always depending on the request sent by the master.

The problem starts when I output(write) to the slave and hear for response. Sometimes the slave replies perfectly, a lot of times no reply at all and sometimes the telegrams are just not what I expected. Should I use like flush or drain? anything???

The Raspberry Pi is basically just the intermediaries, getting data from master and sending it to slave and vice versa. It acts like the middleman. Note that a middleman is not needed since the master can be directly connected to slave but I want to use the data for other purpose. Thanks.

Comment: I’d suggest to make your proxy completely protocol-unaware, retransmitting every byte as soon as it’s received.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I figured out the answer but forgot to post it here. The Raspberry Pi GPIO pin is not the same as Arduino's. The lack of interrupt in Linux OS with Raspberry Pi makes it impossible for the code to work. In short, when Arduino receives serial data, it automatically processes it to the microseconds it received it. But Raspberry Pi uses Linux which only does that when the operating system wants. So when termios or the read function is used, it is not instant. Hence, the Pi cannot be used as intermediaries.